# Adding new properties to constructor function without .prototype

Tags: javascript

when I have function I want to use as a constructor, say:

```
function clog(x){
    var text = x;
    return console.log(text );
}
```

And I have made some instances of it

```
var bla = new clog();
```

Now I want to add new functionality it, so I would use

```
clog.prototype.alert = alert(text);
```

what would be the difference if I simply do:

```
clog.alert = alert(text);
```

Would that not be inherited by the objects that `clog` is their prototype?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Instances created by a constructor function (`clog` in your case) inherit a reference to the `clog.prototype` object. So if you add a property to `clog.prototype`, it will show up on instances. If you add a property to `clog` itself, it will not show up on instances.

There are some issues with your quoted code, so let's look at an abstract example:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.bar = "I'm bar on Foo.prototype";
Foo.bar = "I'm bar on Foo";

var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.bar); // "I'm bar on Foo.prototype"
// E.g., `f` inherits from `Foo.prototype`, not `Foo`

// And this link is live, so:
Foo.prototype.charlie = "I'm charlie on Foo.prototype";
console.log(f.charlie); // "I'm charlie on Foo.prototype";
```

From your comment below:

> I don't understand why new properties added directly to `Foo` would be ignored by the prototype chain?

Because it's `Foo.prototype`, not `Foo`, that is the prototype for objects created via `new Foo()`.

> isn't `prototype` simply points to the constructor object?

No, `Foo` and `Foo.prototype` are completely distinct objects. `Foo` is a function object, which like all function objects can have properties. One of `Foo`'s properties is `prototype`, which is a non-function object that's initially blank other than a `constructor` property that points back to `Foo`. It's `Foo.prototype`, not `Foo`, that instances created via `new Foo` get as their prototype. `Foo`'s only role is to create objects that use `Foo.prototype` as their prototype. (Actually, in `Foo`'s case, it just *initializes* those objects; they're *created* by the `new` operator. With a traditional function like `Foo`, `new` creates the object. If this code were using ES2015+ `class` syntax, `new` wouldn't create the object, it would leave that to `Foo` [if `Foo` were a base class constructor] or `Foo`'s ultimate base class [if `Foo` were  a subclass constructor].)

> If I do `Foo.newProp = "new addition"` why is `f.newProp => undefined`?

*(To avoid confusion, I've changed `Foo.new = ...` to `Foo.newProp = ...` above, since `new` is a keyword. While you* can *use it like you did as of ES5, it's best not to.)*

Because `Foo.newProp` has virtually nothing to do with `f`. You *can* find it, on `f.constructor.newProp`, since `f.constructor` is `Foo`.

Some ASCII-art:

Given this code:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.bar = "I'm bar on Foo.prototype";
Foo.bar = "I'm bar on Foo";
```

we have these objects with these properties (some omitted for clarity):

```
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
        |                                       |
        V                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−>| [String]         |  |
| Foo [Function] |    |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |   | "I'm bar on Foo" |  |
| bar            |−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
| prototype      |−−−−+                         |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |                         |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−+              |
                                 |              |
                                 V              |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                               | [Object]    |  |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                               | constructor |−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                               | bar         |−−−−−>| [String]                   |
                               +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                    | "I'm bar on Foo.prototype" |
                                                    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Now if we do

```
var f = new Foo();
```

we have (new stuff in **bold**):

```
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
        |                                          |
        V                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−>| [String]         |     |
| Foo [Function] |    |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |   | "I'm bar on Foo" |     |
| bar            |−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
| prototype      |−−−−+                            |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |                            |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+              |
                                    |              |
                                    V              |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
| f [Object]    |          +−−−−−>| [Object]    |  |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+          |      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
| [[Prototype]] |−−−−−−−−−−+      | constructor |−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                 | bar         |−−−−>| [String]                   |
                                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                      | "I'm bar on Foo.prototype" |
                                                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

([[Prototype]] is an object's internal field referring to its prototype. This is accessible via `Object.getPrototypeOf` [or `__proto__` on JavaScript engines on web browsers, but don't use `__proto__`, it's just for backward compatibility with old SpiderMonkey-specific code.)

Now suppose we do this:

```
f.charlie = "I'm charlie on f";
```

All that changes is the `f` object (new stuff in **bold**):

```
        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
        |                                          |
        V                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−>| [String]         |     |
| Foo [Function] |    |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |   | "I'm bar on Foo" |     |
| bar            |−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     |
| prototype      |−−−−+                            |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    |                            |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+              |
                                    |              |
                                    V              |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
| f [Object]    |          +−−−−−>| [Object]    |  |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+          |      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
| [[Prototype]] |−−−−−−−−−−+      | constructor |−−+  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| charlie       |−−−−−−−−−−+      | bar        |−−−−−>| [String]                   |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+          |      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                           |                          | "I'm bar on Foo.prototype" |
                           |                          +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                           |
                           |      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                           +−−−−−>| [String]           |
                                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                  | "I'm charlie on f" |
                                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

`f` now has its **own** property, called `charlie`. This means that these two statements:

```
console.log(f.charlie); // "I'm charlie on f"
console.log(f.bar);     // "I'm bar on Foo.prototype"
```

Get processed slightly differently.

Let's look at `f.charlie` first. Here's what the engine does with `f.charlie`:

1. Does `f` have its own property called `"charlie"`?
2. Yes; use the value of that property.

Simple enough. Now let's look at how the engine handles `f.bar`:

1. Does `f` have its own property called `"bar"`?
2. No; does `f` have a prototype?
3. Yes; does `f`'s prototype have a property called `"bar"`?
4. Yes; use the value of that property.

So there's a big difference between `f.charlie` and `f.bar`: `f` has its **own** property called `charlie`, but an **inherited** property called `bar`. And if `f`'s prototype object hadn't had a property called `bar`, *its* prototype object (in this case, `Object.prototype`) would be checked, and so on up the chain until we run out of prototypes.

You can test whether a property is an "own" property, btw, using the `hasOwnProperty` function that all objects have:

```
console.log(f.hasOwnProperty("charlie")); // true
console.log(f.hasOwnProperty("bar"));     // false
```

Answering your question from the comments:

> I make `function Person(first_name, last_name) {this.first_name = first_name; this.last_name = last_name;}` and then `var ilya = new Person('ilya', 'D')` how does it resolves the inner `name` properties?

Within the call to `Person` that's part of the `new Person(...)` expression, `this` refers to the newly-generated object that will be returned by the `new` expression. So when you do `this.prop = "value";`, you're putting a property directly on that object, nothing to do with the prototype.

Putting that another way, these two examples result in **exactly** the same `p` object:

```
// Example 1:
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var p = new Person("Fred");

// Example 2:
function Person() {
}
var p = new Person();
p.name = "Fred";
```

---

Here are the issues with the quoted code I mentioned:

**Issue 1:** Returning something from a constructor function:

```
function clog(x){
    var text = x;
    return console.log(text ); // <=== here
}
```

99.9999% of the time, you don't want to return anything out of a constructor function. The way the `new` operation works is:

1. A new blank object is created.
2. It gets assigned a prototype from the constructor's `prototype` property.
3. The constructor is called such that `this` refers to the new object.
4. If the constructor doesn't return anything, or returns something other than an *object*, the result of the `new` expression is the object created in step 1.
5. If the constructor function returns an object, the result of the `new` operation is that object instead.

So in your case, since `console.log` doesn't return anything, you just remove the `return` keyword from your code. But if you used that `return xyz();` construct with a function that returned an object, you'd mess up your constructor function.

**Issue 2:** Calling functions rather than referring to them

In this code:

```
clog.prototype.alert = alert(text);
```

you're **calling** the `alert` function and assigning the result of it to a property called `alert` on `clog.prototype`. Since `alert` doesn't return anything, it's exactly equivalent to:

```
alert(text);
clog.prototype.alert = undefined;
```

...which probably isn't what you meant. Perhaps:

```
clog.prototype.alert = function(text) {
    alert(text);
};
```

There we *create* a function and assign a reference to it to the `alert` property on the prototype. When the function is called, it will call the standard `alert`.

**Issue 3:** Constructor functions should be initially capped

This is just style, but it's **overwhelmingly** standard: Constructor functions (functions meant to be used with `new`) should start with an upper case letter, so `Clog` rather than `clog`. Again, though, this is just style.

Comment: I don't understand why new properties added directly to `Foo` would be ignored by the prototype chain? isn't `prototype` simply points to the constructor object? If I do `Foo.new = "new addition"` why is `f.new => undefined`?

Comment: @IlyaD: No, `Foo` and `Foo.prototype` are completely separate things. `Foo` is a function object, and like all objects it can have properties. One of those properties is `prototype`. In contrast, `Foo.prototype` is a non-function object which is initially blank. It's `Foo.prototype`, not `Foo`, that participates in the prototypical inheritance. `Foo`'s only role in prototypical inheritance is to create objects (in combination with the `new` operator) that use `Foo.prototype` as their prototype.

Comment: but all `Foo.prototype` does is pointing at `Foo`! so if `Foo` initially has a property like `function Foo() {this.bar = "this bar!"}` then creating `x = new Foo()` would give us access to `x.bar` right? so what is the difference between this and doing `Foo.prototype.bar`??

Comment: or between this and doing `Foo.bar = "foobar"` and then creating new instance and accessing it?

Comment: @IlyaD: *"but all `Foo.prototype` does is pointing at `Foo`!"* No, that's the mistake you're making. Repeating what I said above: **they are completely separate things**. I've added some ASCII-art to the answer to try to help. *"or between this and doing Foo.bar = "foobar" and then creating new instance and accessing it?"* All that `Foo.bar = "foobar"` does is add a property to the `Foo` object called `bar`. No instances are created, and there's no effect on the prototype chain.

Comment: wow! thanx for the detailed answer, I'd give you 100 +1 if I could for the effort :) still I cant understand something: I make `function Person(first_name, last_name) {this.first_name = first_name; this.last_name  = last_name;}` and then `var ilya = new Person('ilya', 'D')` how does it resolves the inner `name` properties? if I follow your logic then if it's not `Person.prototype.last_name` it won't work? or am I missing something because it obviously works. so how does `ilya` get access via the prototype chain to `Person`'s properties?

Comment: @IlyaD: No worries, glad this helps. I've updated the answer again to address your question above.

Comment: This is one of the most amazing answers I've ever read on SO.

Comment: WOW! you just nailed it man. Thank you for this great answer!

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `clog.alert` function would simply a attach static function to the `clog` object. It will not be inherited and will not have access to the instance created with `new clog();` in the alert function.

Adding `clog.prototype.alert` will make the `new clog();` object you create inherit the function, and you will also have access to the instance inside using the `this` keyword.

```
function John() {
    this.id = 1;
}

John.doe = function() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.id); // undefined
}

John.prototype.doe = function() {
    console.log(this);
};

John.doe(); // the John object

var me = new John();
me.doe(); // the instance, inherited from prototype
console.log(me.id); // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Any property added to the constructor will act as a static property that can only be accessed by referring to the constructor object (ie, function) and not using any instance object of it.
Its like a Class property and not an instance property.