# How do I obfuscate global variable using YUI without putting entire class inside a closure

Tags: javascript, yui, minify

Suppose there is a global variable which is a function

```
function MyClass(){}
```

and there are methods of this class such as

```
MyClass.func1 = function()
{
}
```

I want to ensure that YUI compression and obfuscation works without putting entire class inside a closure like

```
(function () {
    function MyClass(){}
    MyClass.func1 = function()
    {
    }
})();
```

Is there a way to make YUI compression work without doing this?

Comment: I am afraid that YUI compression ignores global variables, any particular reason why u want class to be global? Reference link http://alistapart.com/article/javascript-minification-part-II

Comment: @RaunakKathuria Yes, One because it is an existing product, and also because keeping the class global ensures that only one instance can be created of that class.

Comment: keeping the class global has nothing to do with the number of instance that can result...

Comment: If what you need is a single instance you should use the singleton pattern. Making your class global does not automatically gives you that.

Comment: @dandavis No, it doesn't. But by keeping a class global I meant that reference to the class is global. Means that a developer doesn't have to create an instance of the class by doing new className();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suppose you could wrap it in an anonymous function before compressing it, and then just remove the anonymous function after.

Also make sure you're using prototype ;)

```
(function () {
  function MyClass(){}
  MyClass.prototype.func1 = function()
  {
  }
})();
```

Results in:

```
(function(){function a(){}a.prototype.func1=function(){}})();
```

And just take out the anonymous function:

```
function a(){}a.prototype.func1=function(){}
```

Comment: I am not using prototype, and it is too much of a change at this point in time. Is there a way to do it without using prototype?

Comment: Well, prototype is useful for creating instances of an object.  It can still be used in the way you are, but new instances of MyClass won't have access to MyClass.func1.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582341/adding-new-properties-to-constructor-function-without-prototype)